# WSO2 identity server restart issues

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, classnotfoundexception

We are trying to install wso2Identity Server version 5.11.0 (https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/previous-releases/ )

We are using postgreSQL version 14.2
We have updated our environment specific values in  deployment.toml
Downloded latest JDBC driver postgresql-42.5.0.jar and placed in /path/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/components/lib from ref: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/
Updated current wso2carbon.jks in /path/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/resources/security
while restarting we are seeing below error and could not able to get the wso2is console, getting blank page please refer the attached screenshot. Please suggest.

```
TID: [-1234] [api#identity#user#v1.0] [2022-11-06 22:59:08,782] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuth2ServiceComponent} - Error while activating OAuth2ServiceComponent. org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error while loading the top scope id for the tenant: -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.dao.ScopeClaimMappingDAOImpl.hasScopesPopulated(ScopeClaimMappingDAOImpl.java:398)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuth2ServiceComponent.activate(OAuth2ServiceComponent.java:108)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:227)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.deactivate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:205)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.deactivate(ServiceComponent.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.deactivate(ServiceComponentProp.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.unregisterServices(ServiceRegistry.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.close(BundleContextImpl.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1029)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1753)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:220)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.exceptions.TransactionException: Could not get the connection from the datasource.
        at org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.withTransaction(JdbcTemplate.java:77)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.dao.ScopeClaimMappingDAOImpl.hasScopesPopulated(ScopeClaimMappingDAOImpl.java:384)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class:  from ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@51a5317a[jdbc-pool:9.0.35.wso2v1(id=71)];ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@372ea2bc
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:292)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvdt5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvdt5.png)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
        at org.wso2.carbon.database.utils.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.withTransaction(JdbcTemplate.java:70)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class:  from ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@51a5317a[jdbc-pool:9.0.35.wso2v1(id=71)];ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@372ea2bc
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:281)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38)
        ... 61 more
```

We are trying to install WSO2 identity server 5.11

Comment: Can you try by changing the connector to `postgresql-42.2.0.jre7`?

Comment: What is the exact update level of 5.11.0 you are using?

Comment: Try using https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.7/postgresql-42.2.7.jar